# How to use yield with dashboard sidebar to show contents on same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app with a functionality quite similar to yelp with a dashboard for customers where they can edit their place but also change their acccount settings, etc. A customer can only have one place for now.

I've created a dashboard controller, views with a partial for the sidebar and everything is working so far but my problem is that when clicking on a link in the sidebar it yields to the application.html.erb. I want to yield everything from the sidebar to the main part of the dashboard/index.html.erb

So my question is how do I yield the things I click in my sidebar to the part on the right next to the sidebar on the page. Basically the functionality is like a navbar on top (only for logged in customers) but I get confused with two yields. I tried "content_for" and <%= yield :sidebar %> but didn't figure out how to get it working yet. Also I am using devise with a user and customer model which share the views and have the functionality for the customer to edit his user account in the dashboard sidebar which might cause a problem with "content_for"?

Please note that I am still learning ruby on rails and am very happy for any kind of input!

dashboard_controller.rb

```
def index
  @place = Place.where(customer_id: current_customer.id).first
end
```

dashboard/index.html.erb

```
<div class="content">
   <div class="sidebar">
      <%= render 'dashboard/sidebar' %>
   </div>
   <div class="main">
      <%= yield %>
  </div>
</div>
```

_sidebar.html.erb

```
<li class="nav-link">
  <%= link_to "<span class='fa fa-cog'></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit".html_safe, edit_place_path(@place) %>
</li>
<li class="nav-link">
  <%= link_to "<span class='fa fa-cog'</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Settings".html_safe, edit_customer_registration_path %>
</li>
<li class="nav-link">
  <%= link_to "<span class='fa fa-sign-out'></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Log Out".html_safe, destroy_customer_session_path, method: :delete %>
</li>
```

application.html.erb

```
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/shared/header' unless @disable_navbar %>
  <%= yield %>
  <%= render 'layouts/shared/footer' unless @disable_footer %>
</body>
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield

Answer (score 0):

> Within the context of a layout, `yield` identifies a section where content
>   from the view should be inserted.
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield

So no - yield will not "yield" to your `dashboard/index.html.erb`. Rather if you want it to have a different layout you should [create a layout](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts).

Lets look at an example:

```
<% # app/views/layouts/application.html.erb %>
<body>
  <nav id="top-menu">
   <h1><%= link_to 'MyApp', root_path %></h1> 
   <ul>
     <%= yield :nav_links %>
     <%# lets provide some default content for nav_links %>
     <% content_for :nav_links do %>
       <li><%= link_to 'Products', products_path %></li>
     <% end %>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="main">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here we create a named yield in the layout called `:nav_links` and also add some "default" content with `content_for :nav_links`.

So lets look at what happens when we render `/products/index.html.erb`:

```
<div class="products">
  <% if @products.any? %>
    <%= render @products %>
  <% else %>
    <p>No products are available at this time</p>
  <% end %>
</div>
<%# we also want to add a contextual navigation link %>
<% content_for(:nav_links) do %>
  <li><%= link_to 'Sales', sales_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

The rendered result is:

```
<body>
  <nav id="top-menu">
   <h1><a href="/">MyApp</a></h1> 
   <ul>
     <li><a href="/products">Products</a></li>
     <li><a href="/products">Sales</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="products">
      <p>No products are available at this time</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Rails inserts the content from the view into the "main" layout and the content from `content_for(:nav_links)` is concatenated into the buffer.

> Also I am using devise with a user and customer model which share the
>   views and have the functionality for the customer to edit his user
>   account in the dashboard sidebar which might cause a problem with
>   "content_for"?

The only problem you may have is a "namespace collision" - if you are using `yield :sidebar` and a gem for example is also using the same name for a yield you may have unexpected results.